# SQLAlchemy Update or Insert Function

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

New to using SQLAlchemy and ORM in general.
I have a function I would like to call on an object and depending on whether or not an existing id has been passed to the function INSERT or UPDATE the DB.

```
def storeFoo(self,session,FooObj=None,Fooid=None):
    if Fooid:
        Foo = session.query(ConfFoo).\
                    filter(ConfFoo.id == self.id).first()
        #Update Values
        Foo.name = self.name
        Foo.startdate = self.startdate
        Foo.enddate = self.enddate
        Foo.timeperiod = self.timeperiod
        Foo.users = self.users
        Foo.keywords = self.keywords
        Foo.type = self.type
        Foo.perms = self.perms
        session.add(Foo)

    else:
        Foo = ConfFoo(name = FooObj.name, startdate=FooObj.startdate,
                            enddate = FooObj.enddate, timeperiod = FooObj.timeperiod,
                            users = FooObj.users, keywords = FooObj.keywords,
                            type = FooObj.type, perms = FooObj.perms)
        session.add(Foo)
```

Comment: If `id` is the primary key then you should do `.one()` instead of `.first()` in the update case.  Also you can move the `session.add` call to outside the if/else, so you only have it once.  Besides that, what you have looks fine.

Comment: Thanks. I added session.commit() and it saved fine

Comment: @wberry: in fact for PK one probably should use `Query.get`: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html?highlight=query#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get